# What should be the fate of the "Learning garbage collection theory" question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Despite its high score and thousands of views, this personally strikes me as a pretty awful question with pretty awful answers: [Learning garbage collection theory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1318631/1709587)

The question is awful because it's vague and opinion-based and outside our normal scope. Note that the question asks what the *prerequisites* are for learning about garbage collection, and how to do so.

Such a question difficult to answer in the first place. Are we allowed to assume minimal programming skills? Unclear. What exactly are the boundaries on "garbage collection theory", as the OP defines it? The notion of "prerequisites" works well for concrete books or lecture courses but not so well for vaguely-defined subject areas: anything that one person argues is a prerequisite, another could just as well argue is *part* of "garbage collection theory".

The answers, too, all strike me as unhelpful in their own ways:

- The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1319064/1709587) is the most incredible instance of a link-only answer I've ever see - it contains no meaningful content itself but instead links to *a page of links* to *paywalled* papers that together costs hundreds of dollars. It also doesn't even attempt to address the question of prerequisites.
- The [next answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1318665/1709587) lists multiple resources but again has no real content of its own, and again makes no attempt to address what the "prerequisites" are.
- The [next answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4522898/1709587) is link-heavy again but undeniably has some useful content in the answer itself. It's, to my mind, the only slightly redeeming thing on the page.
- Next we have what is [basically another link-only answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1318649/1709587).
- And a [paper-only answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1499904/1709587)
- [And another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1318686/1709587)
- [And a book recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1318696/1709587).

This... all seems a bit rubbish. Even if the question as worded is not *quite* a resource recommendation request, that's how it has in fact been interpreted.

I'm in favour of a mod just deleting the whole lot. It's *basically* just a big collection of links, many of them paywalled, and I don't think that's a helpful thing to keep around.

Does anyone disagree? Other courses of action I can imagine people supporting are:

- Historical lock
- Deleting all the link-only or paper-only answers and keeping around only [Jon Harrop's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4522898/1709587)

Comment: @Jeremy Note, if you haven't already, that that list of papers is just the reading list of a particular lecture course, which already exists elsewhere on the internet. It's not been hand-curated by the answerer. That very much moves me in the direction of "delete" rather than "historical lock", personally.

Comment: What do we gain by deleting this?  Thousands of people have viewed it and a good proportion of those found it useful enough to upvote.  Its not likely to prevent people who aren't interested in it from finding something they're looking for.  What is gained by deleting this?

Comment: @GregoryArenius The site would be cleaner and it would have one less [broken window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_windows_theory).

Comment: @GregoryArenius A reasonable question. I think we gain a few things. We stop people using it as a dupe target for any and all questions about garbage collection they think are stupid. Broad "Basics of X" questions are prone to misuse as dupe targets; such use provides a way of saying "You're stupid, go read a tutorial" by way of the closure system. (The "Linked" sidebar reveals a handful of such uses in this case.) We eliminate the impression that such questions are welcome here - a "broken window" as Tiny Giant puts it. And we save Googlers one hop on their way to finding useful information.

Comment: 4000 people have viewed it in 8 years, which is about 2 a day, and its received 20 odd votes. The question is low quality, the answers are the same, personally i think entire post has no value at all

Comment: I very much agree with all the comments above. However, as well as having one fewer broken window on the site, we may have a community of users who have found what they consider a useful resource only for it suddenly either to disappear or become festooned with stickers they will interpret to say "This is a BAD thing". It's a great shame that this question wasn't identified and dealt with when it was first asked. I fear it's too late now and we should leave it as-is.

Comment: `"Despite its high score"` I was expecting like, 1k+ scores :P

Comment: Agree on the "misuse as dupe target" part, but @MarkAmery even if the list is "hand-curated" by the lecturer of the answer poster, it may still be more useful than some Google search result.

Comment: Why worry about it? We should be worrying about posts that give wrong or misleading information, but where there's a helpful answer to a question that doesn't meet the highest standards, it does no harm: haven't you got anything better to do?

Comment: @MichaelKay I landed there in good faith and it took minutes to determine that the content linked to in the top answer wasn't freely available to me (had to sign up to ACM to confirm). I'm happy to say it does harm, because it harmed me. Now multiply by 4431 views and you've got a page that has perhaps consumed man-weeks of human labor and provided - it seems to me - nothing in return. Leave it be, and the false promise it provides will burn man-weeks more. If our goal as a site is to surface good information quickly, removing useless questions that slow people down should be part of that.

Comment: I would have cast a delete vote on it already if it weren't for the question closed as a dupe blocking that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The question has now been closed, which I agree with. As others have said, it's clearly too broad for Stack Overflow, and even the most charitable interpretation of it is as a resource recommendation (as evidenced by the answers).

Despite the question being off-topic, the answers were all provided in good faith and do seem to provide some useful, relevant information, so I'm rather disinclined to mod-delete them.

I did delete one of the answers, which was a clear duplicate of the "master article list" provided by Sam Harwell, and therefore was indisputably adding no value. I'm leaving the other answers intact *for now*, but **I've added all of the content to the [garbage-collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/garbage-collection) [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/garbage-collection/info)**, which is a more appropriate home for this type of information *and* allows it to be maintained going forward by the community.

Despite having been off-topic for far longer, the question was only closed on April 12th, so I'm holding off on deletion of the whole lot for the moment.

I see no compelling motivation to delete individual answers. If you want deletion, then the whole question should be deleted. If you're keeping the question, then you should keep the answers that remain, as they are clearly relevant and appropriate to the question.

Comment: "I'm rather disinclined to mod-delete them" if we move all the information elsewhere, can it then be deleted?

Comment: I already moved the information elsewhere, @Braiam. It's in the tag wiki now. So, yes...ultimately I think the question should probably be deleted, but as I said, it's only been closed for a little over a week, so I'd prefer to give the community a little more time to weigh in before deleting. There hasn't exactly been a strong consensus in the answers to this Meta question, either.

Comment: I'm... not exactly a fan of putting the giant list of paywalled papers into the Wiki. I will at least go and add a note before the list that they are behind a paywall and not all available at SciHub, since ACM doesn't clearly disclose this until you've gone through their signup process, and I don't want to send more people down that obnoxious rabbithole for nothing.

Comment: I'm vehemently against paywalls, but that's a soapbox for another time. Academic papers do tend to be behind paywalls, especially the older ones, and there's very little that we can do about that. It doesn't make the content any less valuable, and it's really not the authors' fault, so I don't really understand the motivation to pretend/act as if it doesn't exist. If you have a complaint about the UX of accessing the paper, you should forward that to the relevant parties. @Mark

Comment: @CodyGray The paywall very much affects the value of the resource to (I imagine) the large majority of readers who will simply be unwilling to pay for access to those papers, full stop. It makes sense to warn them up-front that the resource is useless to them, before wasting minutes of their time. Doing otherwise makes the inclusion of the list do more harm than good, IMO.

Comment: @MarkAmery If you can at least see the authors of the papers, you have a very good chance of getting a copy of their paper simply by emailing and asking. You could even just ask them to upload a copy to arXiv.org, and then you could use links to there instead.

Answer (score 15):

If we're going to leave the question undeleted, as [Pikachu the Purple Wizard suggests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382841/1709587), I recommend that we at least purge *all* the answers besides [Jon Harrop's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4522898/1709587).

Jon's answer at least provides some concrete information about the nature of garbage collection and the names of the four key garbage collection algorithms. The other answers, by contrast, all contain no information at all besides links to lecture courses, books, or papers. They would be eligible for deletion as "link-only" answers on any other question, and I don't see a reason to privilege them here.

Reaching the page and immediately seeing Jon Harrop's answer might actually be useful to me. Reaching it and being directed by [Sam Harwell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1319064/1709587) to spend minutes of my life trying to gain access to a reading list that turns out to be paywalled and not all available of SciHub? Not so much.

Comment: I happen to work at a university, so I'll have access to most of those papers in the accepted answer, but indeed, if you don't do anything to answer a question but to drop a 20 page reading list, you shouldn't have answered to begin with. I'd be in desperate need, were I to spend neigh on two weeks reading papers for this question, especially having Harrop's answer giving a proper summary of the subject matter. Delete the whole question imo (it's not that many votes/views I'd say), or purge all but Harrop's answer indeed.

Comment: I think link-only answers are more commonly converted to comments?

Comment: I have mixed feelings about deleting the reading list... academic papers are far less likely than most links to rot away forever, and if we're leaving a question as broad as "how do I learn garbage collection theory" up, then an answer of "read the following garbage collection papers to learn garbage collection theory" doesn't seem wholly inappropriate.

Comment: @user202729 that can only happen if a mod handles it, and that is less likely than it being handled by the community through review.

Answer (score 3):

I think we should close it, but not delete it.

Hopefully we can all agree that it's off-topic. It's too broad (it's asking multiple very large questions at once) *and* opinion-based. There is no doubt in my mind that it should be closed.

I do not, however, believe it should be deleted. As seen in [the timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1318631/timeline), the score would have been +22 yesterday. Most likely the three downvotes and one upvote came from the meta effect of this question being asked.

My point is, a lot of people seem to think it's been helpful. It has almost 4500 views and has lots of upvotes and no downvotes before this meta question was asked. It's been helpful to a fair number of people, and we should not be removing useful content from the site.

Comment: Just saying: a subway map of [pick your city] could also be useful to some people. With good SEO, even certainly more than 20 random individuals in 10 years.

Comment: And if those links go down? It's useful to how many people? Let's kill those sites and wait 10 years to see how many downvotes it receives..

Comment: I see no links. Maybe you should look again?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Most of those links are to academic publications which have a rather better survival record than internet question-and-answer sites.

Comment: @Kaiido and if such a map was not harmful by being _inaccurate_ (leaving aside whether something is factually incorrect), would that be harmful amidst the literally millions of other "resources" people will stumble upon on this site?

Comment: @roganjosh For one, people who would see it may think it's an ok post, while we all know it's not.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I was feeling like wasting a bit of time so I dug up most of the papers through Google Scholar, put them on the Internet Archive (2/3 were already on there) and suggested an edit. If the edit gets approved and helps guide the discussion here on meta, there you go. If not, now I have access to some papers I myself would like to read.

**Edit for posterity:** My suggested edit to add all the papers was rejected, and furthermore it was also suggested that what I tried to do was academic theft. This latter point could be true - I don't mind the point - but I also honestly don't know if it's considered theft to archive freely available articles (that's freely available because a university is hosting it on AWS). Regardless, all of this suggests to me that if it's not appropriate to improve the post with links, and people think it doesn't stand alone without links (the need for the actual papers was mentioned a lot in comments), then many of the answers on that post are very problematic indeed.

Comment: You know, I'm not sure. Deleting my comment.

Comment: I don't know about academic theft technicalities, but as per [Cody's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/383172/7795130), all that answer's information was added to the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/garbage-collection/info), so the suggested edit should probably be to the wiki rather than the answer.

Comment: @DavyM that's a really good idea, thanks. I'll see if I can figure out from terms of service or elsewhere if what I'm trying to do is a problem, although I'm no lawyer so it might be best to just leave it be. I do wonder if it'd be better to use the direct university-hosted links - I only went with archiving to try to prevent link rot. Hrm... (Some of this is probably just sunk cost fallacy talking since it took time to get ~30 links)

Comment: We here at Stack Exchange tend to leave the legal wrangling to the lawyers, or at least the Stack Exchange employees, who are advised by lawyers. I’d err on the side of providing the content, assuming full attribution is provided in accord with academic standards (and it has been). The author(s) will be satisfied with that; if a predatory publisher wants to serve SE with a takedown notice, that’s their prerogative—and, importantly, not your or my problem.

Comment: @CodyGray I appreciate your comment. I've re-submitted an edit request, this time to the wiki

Comment: Thanks for the ping. Glad we got that sorted. :-)